# Mongodb selecting every nth of a given sorted aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, query-optimization

I want to be able to retrieve every nth item of a given collection which is quite large (millions of records)

Here is a sample of my collection

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("614965487d5d1c55794ad324"),
  hour: ISODate("2021-09-21T17:21:03.259Z"),
  searches: [
    ObjectId("614965487d5d1c55794ce670")
  ]
}
```

My start of aggregation is like so

```
[
  {
    $match: {
      searches: {
        $in: [ObjectId('614965487d5d1c55794ce670')],
      },
    },
  },
  { $sort: { hour: -1 } },
  { $project: { hour: 1 } },
  ...
]
```

I have tried many things including

- `$sample` which does not make the pick in the good order
- Using `$skip` makes it very slow as the number given to `skip` grows
- Using `_id` instead of `$skip` but my ids are unfortunately not created in an ordered manner

My goal is thus to retrieve the `hour` of a record, every 20000 record, so that I can then make a call to retrieve data by chunks of approximately 20000 records.

I imagine it would be possible to

- sort, and number every records, then keep only the first, 20000, 40000, ..., and the last

Thanks for your help and let me know if you need more information

Comment: Don't you think you are better off doing the `$match` before the _sort_ (you will be sorting less data)?

Comment: Sure I can, but it does not change the problem unfortunately. I will change my original question considering your answer. Thanks

Comment: How many documents are there after the `$match` stage?

Comment: There are millions

Comment: You can try this approach: group all data into an array (has limitation with large number of documents). Then, iterate the array (can use an aggregate operator like `$reduce`, `$filter`), to get the every nth array element.

Comment: Thanks for the idea but I'm afraid this would not work with that much data.
I though there could be a way to number records easily though